# NodeMailer is blocked on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, smtp, nestjs, nodemailer

I have a NestJS app deployed to a Windows Azure App Service. Like everything else in Azure, it works fine on my machine until I deploy it. Getting a 500 error. It looks like some kind of port restriction.

Error message:

```
DEBUG Creating transport: nodemailer (6.7.2; +https://nodemailer.com/; SMTP/6.7.2[client:6.7.2])
DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP/6.7.2 DEBUG [DJemKiOruKY] 
Resolved localhost as 127.0.0.1 [cache hit]
ERROR [DJemKiOruKY] connect EACCES 127.0.0.1:587
DEBUG [DJemKiOruKY] Closing connection to the server using 'destroy'
```

Here's the code that configures the mailer. Our noreply email has a custom domain (noreply@our_company.com)

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'smtp.office365.com',
            port: 587,
            secure: false,
            requireTLS: true,
            auth: {
                user: process.env.NOREPLY_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                pass: process.env.NOREPLY_EMAIL_PASSWORD
            },
            logger: true
        });

        const info = await transporter.sendMail({
            from: `Sender Name <${process.env.NOREPLY_EMAIL_ADDRESS}>`,
            to: process.env.NOREPLY_EMAIL_RECIPIENT,
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifically allow outbound traffic on port 587.

How you do this depends on your setup.

To verify that the port is open, go to the app service console:

```
tcpping smtp.office365.com:587
```

Comment: That's odd, it worked. It did 4 attempts and all 4 passed

Comment: Have you added Nodemailer as a dependency in package.json?

Comment: Yeah, the code wouldn't compile if I hadn't done that....